# PSPICE: DC Sweep of zener diode characteristics not working

Tags: simulation, pspice

[image]

[image]

As you can see, these are my schematic and DC sweep diagrams. Why am I not getting a characteristic zener diode plot?

Comment: Almost certainly you have a zener rated at more than 14 volts.

Comment: What are the units of the vertical axis? If green trace is V_R1, at 10v, it's showing a vertical value of 10 somethings. It can't be current, since 10v through a 470Ω would be 21.2mA. Could both axes be *volts?* Ehhh....

Comment: @rdtsc How to change the axis? I can't find the options!

Answer (score 1):

Could be either or both issues: 1) You did not specify a BV parameter (breakdown voltage), or 2) Your Y-axis for current is way too big.

If Y-axis for current is same as the voltage (0 to 15) then you will barely make out the current reading. Even if zener was short, that would only be 30 mA at 14 Volts (14V / 470 Ohms). :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to see on the screen? The voltage across the diode? Please note that due to automatic scaling we see only the voltage across R1. This voltage is practiccally identical to the input DC voltage V1. That means: The current is determined by the resistor R1 only and there is no (or only a very small) voltage drop across the diode. It seems you have forgotten to specify the Z-voltage in your model.